# How to run all tests before pushing to GitHub?

Tags: git, github, rspec, continuous-integration, jasmine

Is there a service that offers this functionality:

When pushing to GitHub, it runs all RSpec and Jasmine tests. If any test fails, it rejects the push.

Comment: Can't you just make a shell script for that?

Comment: @zneak Probably not forcefully for other people as I'm guessing by the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Gerrit/Jenkins combination](http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/02/gerrit-git-review-with-jenkins-ci.html). We use it to build our C++ code before it gets pushed to the real branch. You can also set it up to run tests before pushing it to the real branch. I think you can also set it up to use [Github](http://wiki.openstack.org/GerritJenkinsGithub).

Comment: Is there really a chance to use gerrit with github? As far as I know gerrit only manages it's own repository. - If you know of any way to make gerrit use a remote repository, I would be happy to hear about it.

Comment: The idea is that your push to Gerrit, it builds and runs the tests, and only when all that passes your commit is pushed to github. See also this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724101/github-gerrit-hudsonjenkins-workflow

Answer (score 4):

Rejecting pushes can be done by githooks. A hook is typically just a script which exits with status 0 or 1. Depending on that result the action is allowed or disallowed.

See `man githooks` for a list of available hooks and how they work.

Also github seems to allow you to configure your hooks: http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/